# What is error 22 from setsockopt?

Tags: c++, setsockopt

I have the following code that is returning an error number of 22. I can't find out anywhere what 22 refers to, can someone point out where I might find out?

```
  if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY,
                 (char *)&arg, sizeof(arg)) < 0) {
    log.debug("unable to setsockopt TCP_NODELAY: %d", errorNumber());
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Its defined in `errno.h` or somewhere close to it. I would guess it to be EINVAL, but its really implementation dependent. You should check your return values with error code defines, not numeric values.

Answer (score 1):

It's system specific.

Use e.g. `strerror(3)`, `strerror_r(3)` or `perror(3)` to see error description.